# how to give lpad in order by in laravel eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I have SQL query as
order by LPAD(`applicants`.`application_no`, 36, 0) asc
How to give this in laravel eloquent.

I have tried using
orderBy(lpad('applicants.application_no', 36, 0), 'ASC')
But getting Call to undefined function App\Http\Controllers\Schooladmin\lpad().

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You either use

```php
orderBy(DB::raw('LPAD(applicants.application_no, 36, 0) ASC'))
```

or

```php
orderByRaw('LPAD(applicants.application_no, 36, 0) ASC')
```

https://laravel.com/docs/10.x/queries#orderbyraw